# How to select the entire contents of table 1 and retrieve the last data in table 2 ? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

Table 1:

```
select * from permintaan
```

[image]

Table2 :

```
select * from history
```

[image]

- From table 1, I want to select the entire contents
- From table 2, I want to select `history.status` of the last row of data grouped by `history.id_permintaan`.

If it works then the result will be like this:

[image]

How can I do that? All answers are appreciated.

Note: in `history.id` I'm using auto increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select p.*, h.status from permintaan p inner join
(
    select h1.* from history h1 inner join
    (
      select max(id) as max_id, id_permitaan
       from history
        group by id_permitaan
    ) h2 
    on h1.id = h2.max_id
) h
on p.id = h.id_permintaan
```

Comment: ok I just realized that you need to go by max id in history table . will fix in a few mins

Comment: @satewedos .. check it out now ... I just made an edit.

Comment: BTW i have code is simpler : select * from permintaan p left join history h on p.id=h.id_permintaan where h.id in (select max(id) from history group by id_permintaan);

Comment: that should work but not sure of the left join ... also better to avoid the "IN" clause.

Comment: I just found out that avoiding the clause would be better. can you please explain why is that?

Comment: sometimes there can be a performance impact (not always).  Google "IN Clause Performance SQL Server"